# Async function in mongoose pre save hook not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Calling an async function in a pre save hook is returning me `undefined` for the password. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding `async` here? I've used it successfully in other areas of my app an it seems to be working fine...

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {

  let user = this

  const saltRounds = 10;

  const password = hashPassword(user)
  user.password = password;

  next();

})


async hashPassword(user) {

    let newHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }

    return hash    

  });

  return newHash

}
```

Comment: do you understand that `const password = hashPassword(user)` will be a **Promise** - because that's what `async` functions return (immediately) - therefore, you'd be setting `user.password = a_promise` and calling `next` before the promise has resolved - what the next issue will be, *does pre save hook understand promises*

Comment: In which case, I'd need to use a `password.then(user.password = password)` ? Which makes sense, but I think I need to better my understanding of async/promises

Comment: indeed, and call next **inside** .then ... you could *avoid* .then by making `userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {` - then you can `const password = await hashPassword(user)` - functionally, this is (almost0 identical to the .then pattern

Comment: Got it. Makes sense now.

Comment: of course, other errors in your code include: 1 - `async hashPassword(user) {` - but user is never used in that function. 2 - where does that function get `saltRounds` from? 3 - the callback to .hash will return hash regardless if there's an error or not

Comment: Yeap, you're right. 1)  That was my mistake 2) I should have noted that the saltRounds is defined elsewhere. My bad 3) Again, my mistake. I initially wanted it to just log the error.. I was going to get around to returning it later. Thanks for addressing all those. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd need to handle the promise returned by hashPassword:

```
 hashPassword(user)
 .then(password => {user.password = password
                    next()}
 )
```

I don't think you can turn userSchema.pre  into an async function.

Comment: reading the documentation, the call to `next` continues the "flow" in the case of "serial pre hooks" - so it shouldn't matter what is returned anyway

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose hooks allow async functions in them. It worked for me. Note that the "next" callback parameter is not needed in async functions as the function executes synchronously.

Here is what a correct async/await version of the code posted in the question would be. Please note that the corrections are marked in bold:

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function () {
  
  let user = this;

  const saltRounds = 10;

  const hashed_password = await hashPassword(user.password, saltRounds);

  user.password = hashed_password;

}); // pre save hook ends here

async hashPassword(password, saltRounds) {

  try {

    let newHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);

  } catch(err){

    // error handling here

  }

  return newHash;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clean things up a bit:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }

    this.hashPassword(this.password)
        .then((password) => {
            this.password = password;
            next();
        });
});

userSchema.methods = {
    hashPassword(password) {
        return bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    },
}
```

- `let user = this` can be dropped when using an arrow function in `then`.
- When using `bcrypt.hash()` with no callback, it returns a promise.
- async for hashPassword is redundant when using .then when calling