# Trying to hash a password using bcrypt inside an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799479/async-function-in-mongoose-pre-save-hook-not-working?noredirect=1#comment84602023_48799479).

I feel like I'm almost there, but my incomplete understanding of async is preventing me from solving this. I'm basically trying to just hash a password using bcrypt and have decided to seperate out the hashPassword function so that I can potentially use it in other parts of the app.

`hashedPassword` keeps returning undefined though...

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {

  let user = this
  const password = user.password;

  const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(user);
  user.password = hashedPassword

  next()

})

async function hashPassword (user) {

  const password = user.password
  const saltRounds = 10;

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {

    if (err) {
      return err;
    }

    return hash

  });

  return hashedPassword

}
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> `await` dosent wait for `bcrypt.hash` because `bcrypt.hash` does not
> return a promise. Use the following method, which wraps `bcrypt` in a promise in order to use `await`.

```
async function hashPassword (user) {

  const password = user.password
  const saltRounds = 10;

  const hashedPassword = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve(hash)
    });
  })

  return hashedPassword
}
```

**Update:-**

> The library has added code to return a promise which will make the use
> of `async/await` possible, which was not available
> earlier. the new way of usage would be as follows.

```
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
```

Comment: Might be worth making it clear that you're basically wrapping `bcrypt` in a promise in order to use `await`. Nice solution though!

Comment: I was trying to stay away from using promises, but in this case it clearly needed to be done. Thanks for the solution – it worked :)

Comment: @Modermo I would strongly advise using promises, simply because it's the future of async code. All the fancy new async/await stuff is pinned on top of promises, so it's definitely worthwhile wrapping your head around them. Plus, it makes writing complex async code much _much_ easier.

Comment: Agreed. The async stuff, in my limited experience, is SO much nicer to work with. In this instance though, I really don't know how I could avoid using a promise because I want `hashPassword` to be it's own function.

Comment: Absolutely, a promise is required for async/await. No other way around it because you can't do something like `async return <value>` in a callback (although this is something which would be really neat).

Comment: There's a better solution now, supported by the doc. Please look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63334789/5223309)

Answer (score 25):

By default, `bcrypt.hash(password,10)` will return as promise. please check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

**Example:** Run the code,

```
var bcrypt= require('bcrypt');

let password = "12345";


var hashPassword = async function(){
    console.log(bcrypt.hash(password,10));
    var hashPwd = await bcrypt.hash(password,10);
    console.log(hashPwd);
}

hashPassword();
```

**Output:**

```
Promise { <pending> }
$2b$10$8Y5Oj329TeEh8weYpJA6EOE39AA/BXVFOEUn1YOFC.sf1chUi4H8i
```

When you use `await` inside the async function, it will wait untill it get resolved from the promise.

Comment: how do we then retrieve the password ?

Comment: @LV98 hashing is a one-way function and you won't be able to retrieve the password from hashed password. Also, if you run the code multiple times, you will see that the hashPwd changes as you generate new salt every time. So if you want to compare the passwords, you must use `bcrypt.compare`, as it is almost impossible to generate the same hash.

Comment: @nick, I think Squirrel.98 is asking how do you/we retrieve the generated hash. I imagine you could just return hashPwd after the await statement runs...

Answer (score 6):

use The method bcrypt.hashSync(), It is Synchronous out of the box.

```
const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password,saltRounds);
```

Comment: hashSync() is the synchronous version of hash, so you don't need to await it. Because asynchronous one returns promise, which needs to be awaited. You can use synchronous one like const hashed = bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds)

Comment: Oh, actually you are right. I didn't realize that at the moment. I have edited my response. Thank you

Comment: @PrivateOmega the docs says, if your using bcrypt on a server, async is preferred:

A Note on Timing Attacks Why is async mode recommended over sync mode?
 
If you are using bcrypt on a simple script, using the sync mode is perfectly fine. However, if you are using bcrypt on a server, the async mode is recommended. This is because the hashing done by bcrypt is CPU intensive, so the sync version will block the event loop and prevent your application from servicing any other inbound requests or
events. The async version uses a thread pool which does not block the
main event loop.

Comment: @mike Yes ofcourse, what you wrote down is entirely correct and I know all of that. but I guess at that time, I was just answering to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Hashing bcrypt asynchronously should be like this

```
bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
  if (err) {
     throw err;
  }
  // Do whatever you like with the hash
});
```

If you are confused with sync and async. You need to read more about them.
There are a lot of good articles out there.

Comment: I think I need to understand the `bcrypt.hash` async function better to understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Just went to understand the bcrypt function itself. As Akash said, indeed, `bcrypt.hash` doesn't return a promise, so I need to wrap it in one.

Comment: This may help someone else out there https://stackoverflow.com/a/52087581/1274820

Answer (score 2):

You need to look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises) in the documentation.

> Async methods that accept a callback, return a Promise when callback
> is not specified if Promise support is available.

So, if your function call takes in a callback then you can't use `await` on it since this function signature doesn't return a `Promise`. In order to use `await` you need to remove the callback function. You can also wrap it in a `Promise` and `await` on it but that's a bit overkill since the library already provides a mechanism to do so.

Code refactor:

```
try {
   // I removed the callbackFn argument
   const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const hashedPassword = (password, salt) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrpyt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) reject();
            resolve(hash);
        });
    });
};
hashedPassword('password', 10).then((passwordHash) => {
    console.log(passwordHash);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue...
solved by assigning the Boolean value from a function:

```
compareHash = (password, hashedPassword) => {
if (!password || !hashedPassword) {
  return Promise.resolve(false);
}
return bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword);
 };
```

Here the 2 arguments will not be undefined, which is the cause of issue.
And calling the function:

```
let hashCompare = this.compareHash(model.password, entity.password);
```