# Bcrypt not hashing and salting passwords anymore

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt

In a previous version of my current app I have a working backend app with bcrypt who salts and hashes my passwords. In this version I now work on is a 1 on 1 copy with the same routes, controllers. 
All works perfectly fine, the data from the post request is nice saved but without a hashed password. The blank password is now showing.

I work on windows 10, 64 bit, both versions in my versions are bcrypt are 3.0.4 local installed. I work with mongoDB and mongoose.

I use the most general version of code for [hashing and salting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799894/trying-to-hash-a-password-using-bcrypt-inside-an-async-function). As said, this still works in my elder version.

Anybody has a clue what has changed?

Here the code:

```html
//relevant parts of app.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
//const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');

// connection to mongoose 
require('./app_api/models/db');

//route to routes
const users = require('./app_api/routes/users');

//routes (post request)
router
 .route('/user/signup')
 .post(AuthenticationControllerPolicy.signupPost, ctrlUsers.signupPost); 

//fragment of the post controller
const signupPost = function (req, res) {
 //Make sure this account already exists
 Base.
  findOne({
   userName: req.body.userName
  }, function (user, err) {
   //Make sure user doesn 't already exist
   if (err) {
    return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'The email address you have entered is already associated with another account.' });
   } else { //etc..


//Create and save the user
user = new Base({
password: req.body.password
});
user.save(function (err) {

// base model with hashing and salting code
const baseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 password: { type: String, required: true }
 }, options);

const Base = mongoose.model('Base', baseSchema);

// salting and hashing
      

// hashing and salting before saving
baseSchema.pre('save', function (next) {

 let base = this;
 // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
 if (!base.isModified('password')) return next();

 //generate a salt
 bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
 if (err) return next(err);

 // hash the password using our new salt
 bcrypt.hash(base.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
 if (err) return next(err);

 // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
 base.password = hash;
 next();
  });
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. make sure **const Base = mongoose.model('Base', baseSchema);** is at the end of the code since it is responsible of creating the model and since you have declared it on the top before the **pre** hook it will not be created and the password will not be hashed.

```
    // On Save Hook, encrypt password
    // Before saving a model, run this function
    baseSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
      //get access to the user model
      const base= this;

      // generate a salt then run callback
      bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        // hash (encrypt) our password using the sale
        bcrypt.hash(base.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }

          //overwrite plain text password with encrypted password
          base.password = hash;
          next();
        });
      });
    });

const Base = mongoose.model('Base', baseSchema);
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for helping. Still not understand why this was working in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

I got also problem with the hashing password before creating a new user. That's why we should define the hashing function before model creation. Check out this example. I have defined hashing function before `const User = mongoose.model("user",userSchme);`. That's the point.

```js
    userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  const user = this;
  const saltRounds = Number(process.env.SALT);

  if (this.isModified("password") || this.isNew) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function (saltError, saltRounds) {
      if (saltError) {
        return next(saltError);
      } else {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds, function (hashError, hash) {
          if (hashError) {
            return next(hashError);
          }
          user.password = hash;
          next();
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```