# bcryptjs is hashing password but it is saved raw in database

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, hook, bcrypt

i have registration/login system and for hashing i used third party library bcryptjs and it works (i mean it hashes passwofrd) but problem is that this password is saved raw in database. here is my code of mongoose pre save hook

```
AdminSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
var user = this;
if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTORY, function(err, salt){
    if(err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt,function(err,hash){
       if(err) return next(err);
       console.log(hash)
       user.password = hash;
       console.log(user.password)
       next();
    })
  })
})
```

and here is save method in registration.js

```
 let admin;
  admin = new Admin();
  admin.username = username;
  admin.password = password;
  admin.save(function(err, user){
         if(err){
           console.log(err)
           return res.status(500).send({message:err.message})
         }
           console.log(user)
           const redirectTo = '/';
         return res.status(200).send({redirectTo})

        })
    }
```

when i log user.password in pre hook it shows me hash
but when i log user in `save` it shows me raw text.
what is problem?
Thank you

Comment: Might be an asynchronous issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799894/trying-to-hash-a-password-using-bcrypt-inside-an-async-function

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the string and not referring:

```
user.password = hash.slice();
```

PS: I can't comment, it should be a comment, if it is wrong I will delete this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try This is work for You.

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

let admin;
  admin = new Admin();
  admin.username = username;
  admin.password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
  admin.save(function(err, user){
         if(err){
           console.log(err)
           return res.status(500).send({message:err.message})
         }
           console.log(user)
           const redirectTo = '/';
         return res.status(200).send({redirectTo})

        })
    }
```

Comment: i can not use bcrypt library

Comment: i mean why my code is not inserting hashed password into db